# Have a single instance of Python object listen to sequential of future arguments

Tags: python, stream, instance

Suppose I have a python class with a large overhead

```
class some_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.overhead = large_overhead

    # Get new data
    def read_new_data(self, data):
        self.new_data = data

    def do_something(self):
        # DO SOMETHING.
```

Suppose I want to have it listen to output of another program, or multiple programs, and I have a way to maintain this steady stream of inputs. How do I not initiate a new instance every time given the overhead? Do I create a new script and package the class to maintain its 'live'? And if so, how do I capture the output of the programs if they cannot be in direct communication with the script I'm running without going through a middle storage like SQL or file?

Comment: Other **Python** programs?

Comment: @wwii not necessarily. It could be outputs in bit stream or text. What I'm trying to understand is a good way to approach the general question - either to maintain a class with large overhead or somehow distribute this overhead so as to not waste CPU resources.

Comment: `...not initiate a new instance every time...   `, what do you mean by *every time*??

Comment: @wwii It means when data are coming in to be processed, I don't want to initiate the processing class as a new instance - rather have it 'wait' like apache does for ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lacking specifics...  Use [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) to setup listeners/watchers and register your object's methods as callbacks for when the data comes in - run the whole thing in an event loop.

---

While that was easy to *say* and pretty abstract, I'm sure I would have a pretty steep learning curve to implement that, especially considering I'd want to implement some testing infrastructure.  But it seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm looking for outside of my current area of knowledge.

Comment: @RockyLi - There are lots of worthwhile videos at [pyvideo.org](pyvideo.org)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a class variable:

```
class some_class:
    overhead = large_overhead

    # Get new data
    def read_new_data(self, data):
        self.new_data = data

    def do_something(self):
        # DO SOMETHING.
```

now overhead is only evaluated once when the class is defined, and you can use `self.overhead` within any class instances.

Comment: In this case if the script ends and class purged from memory would that overhead be necessarily loaded again when the class is called? I get that if multiple instances are running at the same time they would share the same overhead.